# How to get live data from a service?

Tags: 7, services

In the UK our weather office provides a live weather [data feed](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/about). I would like my Drupal site to retrieve data from this service.

I've read up on the XML-RPC API that is in Drupal 7 core. I've successfully built a Hello World! module that acts as a client, makes a call to a service, and successfully gets a response.

However, Drupal 7 is old and I'm wondering if I should be looking into a more 'modern' approach. I've read up on the Services module.

Can anyone advise me on what are currently the recommended ways to get data from a service into a Drupal 7 site.

I'm not looking for a weather module. This is an API learning exercise.

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from XML-RPC Drupal I don't think Drupal has an API for consuming remote services (unless you count `drupal_http_request()`). Any module that provides this sort of functionality will probably have such an API, but if you're looking to code it yourself I can't think of much Drupal has that will help apart from helper functions for e.g. building the URL to make the request

Comment: You can use composer manager and include guzzle in a custom module, pretty easy to setup to consume a service. I personally don't have the time atm to elaborate more but maybe in a few days I can write something up that can help until then I would definitely put some research in on those topics.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice. The solution:

For example, to get a three-hourly five-day forecast for Dunkeswell Aerodrome:

```
  $base = 'http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/';
  $resource = 'val/wxfcs/all/json/3840?res=3hourly';
  $api_key = '&key=abcde12345abcde12345';
  $url = $base . $resource . $api_key;
  $response = drupal_http_request($url);
  $data = json_decode($response->data, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most part I think it's something you'll have to build yourself. You can create a module with a "service" and "controller" inside it to get that data. You'll have to use an HTTP request and hit their endpoint for the data you want to retrieve in your controller. Then pass that response to the service in your module and perform whatever actions you need before returning it to the controller. From there your controller can do whatever it needs to with the data. Can send it over to the Javascript side or to another module/controller/service/etc.

I have not seen an easy way to do this with drupal as everything is VERY specific to the API you want to interact with. drupal_http_request() may be of some use for you if you don't know how to make requests.